# Solve for simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve the following problem, but Mathematic is timing out. Any ideas on what to do?

```
Subscript[z, 1] = (b^2/2 - a + Sqrt[(a - b^2/2)^2 + 2*b^2*r])/b^2

Subscript[z, 2] = (b^2/2 - a - Sqrt[(a - b^2/2)^2 + 2*b^2*r])/b^2

Solve[{x*Subscript[z, 1]*(1/(1 + n))^(Subscript[z, 1] - 1) + 
y*Subscript[z, 2]*(1/(1 + n))^(Subscript[z, 2] - 1) + 
l* (-((2 j)/(-a + r)) + 2/((-2 a - b^2 + r) (1 + n))) == 0,x*Subscript[z, 
 1] (Subscript[z, 1] - 1)*(1/(1 + n))^(Subscript[z, 1] - 2) + y*Subscript[z, 
 2]*(Subscript[z, 2] - 1)*(1/(1 + n))^(Subscript[z, 2] - 2) + l* (2/(-2 a - b^2 + r) ) == 0, x*Subscript[z, 1]*(m/(1 + m))^(Subscript[z, 1] - 1) + 
y*Subscript[z, 2]*(m/(1 + m))^(Subscript[z, 2] - 1) + 
l *(-((2 j)/(-a + r)) + (2 m)/((-2 a - b^2 + r) (1 + m))) == 0, x*Subscript[z, 
 1] (Subscript[z, 1] - 1)*(m/(1 + m))^(Subscript[z, 1] - 2) + 
y*Subscript[z, 
 2]*(Subscript[z, 2] - 1)*(m/(1 + m))^(Subscript[z, 2] - 2) + 
l *(2/(-2 a - b^2 + r) ) == 0}, {x, y, n, m}]
```

If it helps, I can assume r>0 and 0<=n,m<=1

Comment: Are there any known constraints on the variables or parameters? Are you looking for all solutions or just real solutions?

Comment: @BobHanlon I added assumptions on r and n,m to the question in case it helps. Real solutions would be ideal, but I'll take any solution.

Comment: @Bill I didn't get a result from the Reduce code you shared

Answer (score 4):

This system can be solved by noticing the first two equations do not contain $m$ and are linear in $x$ and $y$.  So, there may be solutions for $(x,y)=f(n)$.  Likewise, the last two equations do not contain $n$ and are linear in $x$ and $y$, so there may be solutions for $(x,y)=g(m)$.  The solutions for $(x,y)$ will be the same, provided $f(n)$ and $g(m)$ are the same constant (independent of $n$ and $m$).  That's the plan.

#### Rewrite the equations without subscripts

```
orig = {x*z1*(1/(1 + n))^(z1 - 1) + y*z2*(1/(1 + n))^(z2 - 1) + 
     l*(-((2 j)/(-a + r)) + 2/((-2 a - b^2 + r) (1 + n))) == 0, 
   x*z1 (z1 - 1)*(1/(1 + n))^(z1 - 2) + 
     y*z2*(z2 - 1)*(1/(1 + n))^(z2 - 2) + l*(2/(-2 a - b^2 + r)) == 0,
    x*z1*(m/(1 + m))^(z1 - 1) + y*z2*(m/(1 + m))^(z2 - 1) + 
     l*(-((2 j)/(-a + r)) + (2 m)/((-2 a - b^2 + r) (1 + m))) == 0, 
   x*z1 (z1 - 1)*(m/(1 + m))^(z1 - 2) + 
     y*z2*(z2 - 1)*(m/(1 + m))^(z2 - 2) + l*(2/(-2 a - b^2 + r)) == 
    0};
```

where

```
zrules = {z1 -> (b^2/2 - a + Sqrt[(a - b^2/2)^2 + 2*b^2*r])/b^2,
          z2 -> (b^2/2 - a - Sqrt[(a - b^2/2)^2 + 2*b^2*r])/b^2}
```

#### Introduce constants

To make the equations a little more wieldy, introduce constants $c, c_0, c_n, c_m$.

```
crules = {c -> l (-((2 j)/(-a + r))),
   cn -> (2 l)/ (-2 a - b^2 + r),
   c0 -> (2 l)/(-2 a - b^2 + r),
   cm -> (2 l)/(-2 a - b^2 + r)};

eqns = {
  c + cn/(1 + n)  +  (1/(1 + n))^(-1 + z1) x z1  +
                     (1/(1 + n))^(-1 + z2) y z2   ==   0, 
  c0  +              (1/(1 + n))^(-2 + z1) x (-1 + z1) z1 + 
                     (1/(1 + n))^(-2 + z2) y (-1 + z2) z2   ==   0, 
  c + cm*m/(1 + m) + (m/(1 + m))^(-1 + z1) x z1  +
                     (m/(1 + m))^(-1 + z2) y z2   ==   0, 
  c0  +              (m/(1 + m))^(-2 + z1) x (-1 + z1) z1  +
                     (m/(1 + m))^(-2 + z2) y (-1 + z2) z2  ==  0}
```

**Check**

Check that the original equations can be recovered by applying `crules` to `eqns`:

```
orig[[All, 1]] == eqns[[All, 1]] /. crules // Simplify
(*  True  *)
```

#### Solve the linear equations

Solve the first 2 equations for $(x,y)$ in terms of variable $n$

```
sol1 = Solve[eqns[[1 ;; 2]], {x, y}] // Flatten

(*  {x -> ((1/(1 + n))^(2 - z1) (-c - c0 - cn - c n + c z2 + cn z2 +
            c n z2))/(z1 (z1 - z2)), 
     y -> ((1/(1 + n))^(2 - z2) (-c - c0 - cn - c n + c z1 + cn z1 + 
            c n z1))/(z2 (-z1 + z2))}  *)
```

Solve the last 2 equations for $(x,y)$ in terms of variable $m$

```
sol2 = Solve[eqns[[3 ;; 4]], {x, y}] // Flatten

(* {x -> (m (m/(1 + m))^-z1 (-c - c m - c0 m - cm m + c z2 + c m z2 + 
             cm m z2))/((1 + m)^2 z1 (z1 - z2)), 
    y -> (m (m/(1 + m))^-z2 (-c - c m - c0 m - cm m + c z1 + c m z1 + 
             cm m z1))/((1 + m)^2 z2 (-z1 + z2))  *)
```

#### Solve for $n$ and $m$

The first solution $(x,y)$ contains an expression for $x$ in terms of $n$.  We know from the second solution that $x$ is independent of $n$, so the expression in the first solution must be a constant.  Likewise for the expression for $y$.  Here we set either derivative, $x'(n)$ or $y'(n)$, from the first solution equal to zero, solve for $n$, and apply our replacement rules to get a solution for $n$

```
soln = Solve[D[x /. sol1, n] == 0, n] /. crules /. zrules // Simplify // Flatten;
soln = Solve[D[y /. sol1, n] == 0, n] /. crules /. zrules // Simplify // Flatten

(*  {n -> -1 + 1/j}  *)
```

Now use the second solution for $(x,y)$, take the derivatives wrt $m$ and solve for $m$.  It's a little tricky because we end up with 3 distinct solutions for $m$.  The solutions to the equations $x'(m)=0$ and $y'(m)=0$ can be combined an simplified like this:

```
Solve[D[x /. sol2, m] == 0, m] /. crules // Flatten;
Solve[D[y /. sol2, m] == 0, m] /. crules // Flatten;

solm = Union[%, %%] // Sort;
solm[[1]] = First[solm] /. zrules // Simplify;
    
solm    (*  {m -> j/(1-j),
             m -> 0        if Re[z1] < -1,
             m -> 0        if Re[z2] < -1}  *)
```

#### Solve for $x$ and $y$

Now we can use the solution for $n$, `soln`, to obtain $(x,y)$ from `sol1`, or we can use one of the solutions for $m$, `solm[[1]]`, to obtain the same expressions for $(x,y)$ from `sol2`.

```
solxy = sol2 /. solm[[1]] /. crules // Simplify

(*  {x -> (2 j^(2 - z1) l (-r + b^2 (-1 + z2) + a z2))  /
          ((a - r) (2 a + b^2 - r) z1 (z1 - z2)) ,
     y -> (2 j^(2 - z2) l (-r + b^2 (-1 + z1) + a z1))  /
          ((a - r) (2 a + b^2 - r) z2 (-z1 + z2)) }  *)
```

#### Verification

We can verify the solution by applying our 3 replacement rules to the original equations, like this

```
orig /. solxy /. soln /. First[solm] // Simplify

(*  True, True, True, True  *)
```